# Parse error for TYPO3 backend

Tags: php, typo3

following problem:

today i put a typo3 homepage to another server with a different domain and so on. It´s not my first time and as usual i cleared all the caches, filled in the new database information etc.

The Site works perfectly and i can also reach the install-tool. 
The problem is the backend. The first time i see the login mask but i can´t login. It´s loading a very long time. After a refresh i get some warnings and an error about the Cache.

like this:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=18) state=0

Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=16) state=0

parse error
```

after i cleared the cache again it´s the same problem. I only get this warnings after the refresh.

The PHP Version is 5.5

Maybe some of you have an idea what i can try...

Thank you

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version do you use? It seems like the required PHP Version is not right. You may want to try to do a Database Compare (Database analyzer) in Install-Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using apache as webserver, place an `.htaccess` in the webroot of your TYPO3 instance.

[This is the TYPO3 example .htaccess](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/nc_staticfilecache/Configuration/Htaccess.html), however following parts are relevant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In conclusion, "the oldschool" way will make it work, but I recommend to use the example configuration and would only thin it out if needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer and i tried it but it doesn´t work.

Comment: I am 99% sure that a missing or misconfigured .htaccess is your problem. Do you use apache and have placed the example `.htaccess` next to the ´index.php` ?

Comment: yes it´s an apache server and i tried it also with the "old school" thing